# Query Expansion / Synonyms when using POST Method

Tags: google-search-appliance

**The situation**

Our Google Search Appliance `(Software Version: 7.2.0.G.112)` is setup to expand queries using a custom synonyms file containing for example this entry: `{men, mens}`

**The problem**

The search appliance appears to use these synonyms when responding to a GET request but not when responding to a POST request. See the table below

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
|  Request Type   |    Query    |  Result Count  |   Good?   |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
|  GET            |    mens     |  705           |    yes    |
|  POST           |    mens     |  691           |    yes    |
|  GET            |    men      |  706           |    yes    |
|  POST           |    men      |  88            |    no     |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

**The Question**

How can I enable the query expansion/ synonyms for the POST request so it will return (approximately) the same results.

**The Requests in Detail**

Get Request

```
GET /search?q=men&output=xml_no_dtd&client=default_frontend&
   getfields=*&filter=0&start=0&num=25&site=some_value&
   requiredfields=(-core__isblocked.core__brandid:brand.
   (core__catalog:163%252D2101|(inv__0104|inv__3301))) HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Post Request

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 242
Cache-Control: no-cache

q=men&output=xml_no_dtd&client=default_frontend&
getfields=*&filter=0&start=0&num=2&site=some_value&
requiredfields=(-core__isblocked.core__brandid:brand.
(core__catalog:163%2D2101|(inv__0104|inv__3301)))
```

<sup>Bonus question: why is the result for GET and POST for "mens" also different.</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be different.  Can you supply the urls?

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "Query Expansion Policy" in the frontend. Are you sure you are using the the same frontend for both the queries. In my knowledge, the GET/POST method should not affect the search result.

Why isn't stackflow allowing me to add a comment to the question. Gosh..

**UPDATE**

Also, core__catalog:163 -- THis value is different in the GET and POST. Might be something to do with the character encoding/decoding? Can you remove all those requiredfields and just supply 'q' and look for the count?

Comment: We have enabled that in the frontend and both requests are using the same frontend.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check for a simple "q" query first and then build your filters using requriedfields. Your value for " core__catalog" is differently encoded.

Comment: It's true that core__catalog is encoded differently, but that's necessary for the GET request to work, and not the cause of this issue. When I remove the requiredfields completely the GET request returns 5790 results and the POST request returns 682 for "men". For "mens" it's 5780 and 5530 respectively.

Comment: Can you play around with the "entqr" parameter and see how your result set changes for each of the value? from 0 to 3. This will override your frontend query expansion settings. With "entqr=1" the count matches? I do not have a straight answer but only suggest you try out varies things in-and-around synonym which you might have already done?

Comment: I did not know about that parameter, will try it out when back in the office tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Thank you Aswath NS changing the `entqr` parameter to `2` on the POST request gives the same result count as the GET request.

Comment: Great. I would suggest you to read the section under entqr to understand what each param value does. See http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1086546